# Flag as duplicate breaks mobile layout

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, flag-dialog

If I vote as duplicate the design is broken. It is much worse if the question has no answers yet, then the answer box has a higher z-index.

[image]

Comment: Android app or mobile site?

Comment: The mobile website could someone migrate the image? it is impossible on the mobile Android browser. @Tim just the second part with the textarea is a dub. The main aspect is the problem you can see on the screen.

Comment: The whole mobile dupe voting interface is broken. It's a nightmare having to scroll to the bottom in the window only to locate the button

Comment: @gparyani   we can not case cv in android app

Comment: @slhck The whole flagging interface is broken. In my case, the box opens overlapped by the "Your Answer" textbox, making it unusable.